# Cant attach to ephemeral container

Tags: kubernetes

I created an ephemeral container and tried to attach to it. But in the pod status it can't find anything about it. The specs are updated with an empty containerID. Maybe someone knows, how to fix it? (In the second cluster with this version, ephemeral containers are working fine, and in theory the cluster's configs are the same).

The k8s version is v1.20 (ephemeral container are enabled in api, kube-scheduler, etcd, kubelet, kube-controller-manager). Also, now I can`t update the cluster to the latest release.

for example I used this manual to create an ephemeral container: https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/kubernetes-ephemeral-containers/

```
kubectl get pods slim-c5f4b9767-47ldt -n test-ephemeral-cont -o jsonpath={'.spec.ephemeralContainers'} | jq
[
  {
    "image": "busybox",
    "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
    "name": "debugger-4hl96",
    "resources": {},
    "stdin": true,
    "targetContainerName": "app",
    "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
    "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
    "tty": true
  }
]
```

and the status result

```
kubectl get pods slim-c5f4b9767-47ldt -n test-ephemeral-cont -o jsonpath={'.spec.ephemeralContainerStatuses'} | jq
```

I tried to create the containers using the instructions from the link above, and the container should start fine.

Comment: SO is for programming questions